# Why isn't my Event Trace for Windows working?

Tags: winapi, etw

I'm trying to figure out how to use Event Tracing for Windows... but I'm failing.
Why does this code give me the error code `ERROR_WMI_INSTANCE_NOT_FOUND`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Wmistr.h>
#include <Evntrace.h>
#include <evntcons.h>

ULONG NTAPI EtpEtwBufferCallback(IN PEVENT_TRACE_LOGFILE Buffer) { return TRUE; }
VOID  NTAPI  EtpEtwEventCallback(IN PEVENT_TRACE EventTrace) { }

int _tmain()
{
    LPCTSTR loggerName = KERNEL_LOGGER_NAME;
    EVENT_TRACE_LOGFILE logFile = {0};
    logFile.LoggerName = const_cast<LPTSTR>(loggerName);
    logFile.ProcessTraceMode = PROCESS_TRACE_MODE_REAL_TIME;
    logFile.BufferCallback = EtpEtwBufferCallback;
    logFile.EventCallback = EtpEtwEventCallback;
    TRACEHANDLE hTrace = OpenTrace(&logFile);
    ULONG result = ProcessTrace(&hTrace, 1, NULL, NULL);
    // result is ERROR_WMI_INSTANCE_NOT_FOUND
    _tprintf(_T("%u\n"), result);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [ProcessTrace docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364093%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `ERROR_WMI_INSTANCE_NOT_FOUND` means "the session from which you are trying to consume events in real time is not running or does not have the real-time trace mode enabled".

You can start the NT Kernel Logger using [tracelog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553012%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from the Windows Driver Kit, though I don't have the WDK to hand so I haven't tried it.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363691%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) explains how to start the NT Kernel Logger yourself.

Comment: What does tracelog do, exactly? Whatever it does, my program should be able to do as well -- programs like Process Monitor don't need tracelog.

Comment: I actually figured it out before reading the article, but yes, that'd have been helpful; thanks!